# the g++ command returns no such file or directory

Tags: c++, g++

I am new to programming; I'm starting a new job and I have to resume what the fellow before me did.

So I have to run a program called test.cpp in C++. This code contains a header called misc.hpp located in a subfolder of where test.cpp is called include.

When I open the terminal from where test.cpp is and run `g++ test.cpp` it tells me that:

> test.cpp:4:19: fatal error: misc.hpp: No such file or directory.

I also tried the g++ test.cpp -I include/misc.cpp but same thing

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is this a C++ job? Have you done any C++ before? Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: without code we cant tell you anything, cause no one around here is a seer. please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. Thx and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

The `-I` (upper-case i) option is to add a ***directory*** to *search* for header files. It's not for including source files.

So if the header file is `include/misc.hpp` then you should do

```
g++ test.cpp -Iinclude
```

Answer (score 4):

`-I include/misc.cpp` doesn't work because:

- The file is `misc.hpp`, not `misc.cpp`
- You do not include files like this
- `-I` is for include *directories*

So:

```
g++ test.cpp -I include
```

Comment: I did a mistake when asking the question, actually I tried g++ test.cpp -I include/misc.hpp  but it's not working

Comment: You could have looked up the `-I` flag in the documentation and read about it.